# Jquery mobile auto loaded content missing the UI?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Hai I new for Jquery mobile.I want load content when I click a button.content display successfully But the content UI is gone.So please help me solve.

```
[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vijay29/d39k8e6g/1)
```

Comment: Please put the relevant code and markup in the question and state more clearly the problem you are having!

Comment: Bro sorry my mistake.I take lot of time to put the fiddle link.really I dont know how to place the link.Anyway Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the controls to the ui-collapsible-content div of the collapsible and call enhanceWithin() when done to tell jQM to enhance the controls:

```
$('#display_data .ui-collapsible-content').append('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="name">Name</label><input type="text"name="name"id="name"value=""/></div><div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="email">Email</label><input type="text"name="email"id="email"value=""/></div>').enhanceWithin();
```

Comment: bro can you unlock my account.I want one upvote.

Comment: @reegan29, i don't understand. I have nothing to do with locking or unlocking accounts...

Comment: no bro.You are not lock my account.this question have one down vote so Now I con't able to ask question from my account. If you give me the up vote(^).I can able to ask question from my account.